# Get enumeration value of a custom field via PSI

Tags: c#, ms-project-server-2010

I'm looking for a way to retreive enumeration value stored in an MS Project custom field. I've been able to use C# and MS Project PSI to retrive values of base type `ProjectDataSet.TaskCustomFieldsRow`, but when I read data from a custom field which is an enumeration, all the data I get is

> FIELD_TYPE_ENUM = 21
>
> CODE_VALUE = some-GUID-here

What do I do next with this GUID to retreive the value I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIELD_TYPE_ENUM = 21 means it's of type text.

When you have a GUID in the CODE_VALUE, this means that this is a lookup field, and the GUID is referencing the correspondant value in the lookup table. You can check those values in the "LookupTableTree" data table of the lookup table dataset obtained by querying the "lookuptable" service of the PSI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though it's a bit late, it's not less useful.